# Json parsing in swift2

Tags: json, swift2

below is the code used to fetch the location

```
let urlPath: String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=23.8670522,72.1957362&radius=500000&type=gas_station&key=XXXX"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        let request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        let response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>=nil

        do{
            let dataVal = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1, returningResponse: response)
            print(response)
            do {
                if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                    print("Synchronous\(jsonResult)")
                    self.items = jsonResult["results"]! as! NSMutableArray

                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }                
        }catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

Json tree for the google- api is something like :

```
"results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 23.5851143,
               "lng" : 72.37393539999999
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 23.58514825,
                  "lng" : 72.37399585
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 23.58506044999999,
                  "lng" : 72.37389725000001
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/gas_station-71.png",
         "id" : "ba9bbe8a5d0d163047b91838e704af89d1d3c101",
         "name" : "Hindustan Petroleum",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "exceptional_date" : [],
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1632,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104609581363497576784/photos\"\u003ehardik joshi\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAANsR9bz2SvLiRJdxGAmp-D4T0YErb9B-C8IishF_1HSJzSswJ3b0AdL5S8Ai3Gq_ipU2SGiBGPkGEJ9HKIxF1X7cfpT6MAg_soiTdcfywGza1lf2XnDl357l8mEMY4NQ5Iz3KHYntR-U1AEcx63zGtb7ADNf-k4xk9xjghgjtIV4EhDGR6-odHQUSCcGJEbPBA4BGhRSUXpIahTEsKYjz6r6gKOsHH5FAw",
               "width" : 976
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ4W9D39RDXDkRs4zMlToTG4c",
         "rating" : 5,
         "reference" : "CmRSAAAAm154NsKBQjlAoI8ScITF6CYLDgy2IbGQf6pKsyrLSNvKQwfKFIusQBMWoqwP7iXmKhhUNzSPNADsW7sklP-UPfS_ted_QjzYAzUX7ejqvl16bEmwS0c9ck7R9ltbIgvyEhD9wYSzAuEwMd0WHXFEkamXGhRZHyNiBHi0P7KeVEZwFpFCi2bSNQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "gas_station", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "SH-41, Mehsana Road, Mehsana"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 23.85122389999999,
               "lng" : 72.1387823
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/gas_station-71.png",
         "id" : "0bee4f823c5ad84fc47ae6e8b35c78d8e581d2e2",
         "name" : "Essar Pump",
         "place_id" : "ChIJh8XaJ_2HXDkRHH9FupFtoSw",
         "rating" : 4,
         "reference" : "CmRRAAAAJ0cvBsOKc5epLATUl-l6GNTTuGZaIedxQQEUkf3GBPsTqfrKG4qtLby9UzxcBClpSv8kr9JQRk2rsXO1AgNUUmzKx9-_bSc17YtERgFBdY4qLJ89CqKg6TLBbJv1c1bXEhAxkx7Sgp0UnqhtfF_WHJE7GhT7KUQILmWbPXdW7laztO6oWEnsNQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "gas_station", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Vishnunagar, Patan"
      }
```

I need to fetch the latitude and longitude inside the location.

```
 "geometry" : {
                    "location" : {
                       "lat" : 23.85122389999999,
                       "lng" : 72.1387823
                    }
                 },
```

But not able to do it.

Code i had used for this is :

```
  print(self.items[0].valueForKey("geometry"))

            let location = (self.items[indexPath.row])["geometry"]?!["location"]?!.string
            print(location)
```

Please help.
I dont want to use any 3rd party for this.

Comment: It's not parsing. It's mapping. Parsing is done by `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` function.

Comment: @Eimantas thank you for the answer.But how can i achieve this by using NSJSONSerialization ?      I had already write this code          if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

Comment: Have you searched for *results geometry location [swift]* here on SO?Parsing google maps JSON is quite popular. And **do not** use deprecated and thread blocking synchronous API to load data.

Comment: For automatic json parsing, please use the app:- [JSON accelerator](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/json-accelerator/id1198949505?mt=12). It will create the models automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let geometry = (self.items[indexPath.row])["geometry"] as? [String: Any] else {
    fatalError("No geometry key in json")
}

guard let location = geometry["location"] as? [String: Double] else {
    fatalError("No location key in geometry")
}

guard let latitude = location["lat"] as? Double else {
    fatalError("No latitude key in location")
}

guard let longitude = locatin["lng"] as? Double else {
    fatalError("No longitude key in location")
}

let coords = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitdue)
```